# Hear myself in Asus Orion Pro headset

Tags: windows-7, headset

I can hear myself in Asus Orion Pro headset when I'm talking. I believe that this is a kind of configuration problem, could you help me please?

**Solution:**

Control Panel -> Sound -> Properties -> Levels -> Sidetone MUTE

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try opening up the volume mixer (run > sndvol) and mute the microphone input and see if it still pesists? If so this might have something to do with a wrong sound driver being installed.

Comment: Thanks, I found a reason, you was very close. I will put the solution in the question.